# SQL Server Filter Records by Min Int Value of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

This seems straight forward but I'm wondering if there is a better way...

I have a query that returns a set of values..

```
declare @tv_config_levels table (relative_level int, list_item varchar(32))
    
insert into @tv_config_levels (relative_level, list_item) 
values (1, 'UPSSTD')

insert into @tv_config_levels (relative_level, list_item) 
values (2, 'EXPRESS2DAYINT')

insert into @tv_config_levels (relative_level, list_item) 
values (2, 'UPSGROUND')
```

Here are the results...

```
    relative_level   list_item
    --------------   ----------
    1                UPSSTD
    2                EXPRESS2DAYINT
    2                UPSGROUND
```

I want to do something seemingly simple... I want to only included records that contain the min `relative_level`..

```
select *
from @tv_config_levels t
where t.relative_level in (select min(relative_level)
                           from @tv_config_levels cl)
```

This works and returns:

```
   relative_level   list_item
    --------------   ----------
    1                UPSSTD
```

My concern is that I'm running my query twice. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

One straightforward alternative would be to use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM @tv_config_levels cl
ORDER BY relative_level;
```

Comment: I didn't know about "WITH TIES"

Comment: Can you filter with this? I mean to remove the relative_level 2 records... 

I might have two or three relative_level 1 records and I just want to work on those...

Comment: Not sure what your follow up is asking.  If you want to do additional processing on the result set generated by my answer above, you can subquery it.  Otherwise, it already will give you the N records having the smallest `relative_level` value.